# ThreeJs add Texture to a GLTF object surface

Tags: three.js, textures, mesh

I am trying to apply an image dynamically on a gltf loaded mesh.

The code to load the model looks like:

```js
const gltfLoader = new GLTFLoader();
  const url = 'resources/models/mesh.gltf';
  gltfLoader.load(url, (gltf) => {
    const root = gltf.scene;
    scene.add(root);
  })
```

When looking from top the element looks like a rounded rect:

[image: example]

When inspecting the imported mesh I can see that the BufferGeometry has a count of 18.000 points:

[image: BufferGeometry]

Everything works fine however if I apply the texture like this:

```js
const texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( 'textures/land_ocean_ice_cloud_2048.jpg' );
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture } );
root.children[0].material = material;
```

The image is not visible but the mesh is now colored in 1 color.

Is it possible to apply the image just on the top face of the rect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to tell what the problem is without seeing the resulting image. However, I would just assign a new texture like this: `root.children[0].material.map = texture` instead of creating a whole new material, since you don't want to lose all the material attributes that came in the GLTF.

Additionally, `MeshBasicMaterial` always looks flat because [it is not affected by lights](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/materials/MeshBasicMaterial).

Comment: Thanks for the tip with the material - I added a UV map in Blender and exported it again and it worked :)